# Type of a class that has variadict template in another class body

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am not an expert in template metaprogramming, and I am kind of stuck now. Any help would be appreciated.

As an introduction.
I have a class (a bit simplified here):

```cpp
template < int dim, int spacedim, int... structdims >
class TopologyInfo
{
}
```

I can create an instance of `TopologyInfo` with functions:

```cpp
template < int dim, int spacedim, size_t... dims >
auto get_topology_info_imp_( std::integer_sequence< size_t, dims... > )
{
    return TopologyInfo< dim, spacedim, dims... >( );
}

template < int dim, int spacedim, int max_topo_dim_ >
auto get_topology_info( )
{
    return get_topology_info_imp_< dim, spacedim >(
      std::make_index_sequence< max_topo_dim_ >{} );
}
```

This works if I use it like that:

```cpp
auto t = get_topology_info< 3, 3, 3 >( );
```

Type of `t` is `TopologyInfo<3, 3, 0, 1, 2>` which is correct.

So now the problem: how to generate the type of `t` without using `auto`, so I will be able to use the class in question as a member of the other class?
It seems to me that I don't understand fully the mechanisms behind `std::index_sequence` and that the solution should be kind of obvious.

Comment: `decltype(get_topology_info< 3, 3, 3 >( ))`

Comment: Well, that actually works. I used `decltype` to check the type but I never thought I can use it like that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` is just a placehold for the actual type. When you write

```
auto t = get_topology_info< 3, 3, 3 >( );
```

then `t` is of some specific type. The fact that you used `auto` doesn't change that.

If the actual type is too unwieldy to be spelled out or not readily known, you can also use `auto`s cousin `decltype`. For example this is the same as the above:

```
decltype( get_topology_info< 3, 3, 3>( )) t = get_topology_info< 3, 3, 3>( );
```

or if you already have an instance:

```
decltype( t ) s = get_topology_info< 3, 3, 3>( );
```

For a class member you might want to use an alias:

```
using some_meaningful_name = decltype( get_topology_info< 3, 3, 3>( ) );
```

Then

```
struct foo {
   some_meaningful_name bar;
};
```

Comment: This works, apart from `using some_meaningful_name = get_topology_info< 3, 3, 3>( );`. This still needs `decltype( )` around the function.

Comment: @szynka12 oh sorry thats a typo, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Just an extension of `idclev`'s answer:

If you're reusing `get_topology_info` a lot in your code ***with different values***, then you might want to wrap it into its own type:

```
template <int A, dim, int spacedim, int max_topo_dim>
using some_meaningful_name = decltype(get_topology_info<dim, spacedim, max_topo_dim>());
```

So now we can just say:

```
some_meaningful_name<3,3,3> member
```